# Wrap some divs with Two different columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've these divs

```
<div class="content">
<div class="rpost">-115</div>
<div class="lpost">-91</div>
<div class="lpost">-99</div>
<div class="rpost">-181</div>
<div class="lpost">-19</div>
<div class="rpost">-135</div>
<div class="rpost">-85</div>
<div class="lpost">-39</div>
</div>
```

I want whatever the order of the divs, wrap lpost in a div called left_columns, and rpost in a div right_columns.

```
 <div class="left_columns">
    <div class="lpost">-91</div>
    <div class="lpost">-99</div>
    <div class="lpost">-19</div>
    <div class="rpost">-85</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right_columns">
    <div class="rpost">-115</div>
    <div class="rpost">-181</div>
    <div class="rpost">-135</div>
    <div class="rpost">-85</div>
 </div>
```

can use masonry or Isotope and infinite-scroll do this?

Comment: Id needs to be unique. That code won't work.

Comment: @ItamarG3 can use class like class="rpost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `class` instead of `id` here and then you can use `wrapAll`

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  $(this).find(".lpost").wrapAll('<div class="left_columns"></div>')
  $(this).find(".rpost").wrapAll('<div class="right_columns"></div>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="rpost">-115</div>
  <div class="lpost">-91</div>
  <div class="lpost">-99</div>
  <div class="rpost">-181</div>
  <div class="lpost">-19</div>
  <div class="rpost">-135</div>
  <div class="rpost">-85</div>
  <div class="lpost">-39</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but use infinite-scroll have many left_columns and right_columns how to fix this?