# why the wrapAll in infinite-scroll, have many divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The last question is here:
[Wrap some divs with Two different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660306/wrap-some-divs-with-two-different-columns)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.wrapper').each(function() {
      $(this).find(".lpost").wrapAll('<div class="left_columns"></div>')
      $(this).find(".rpost").wrapAll('<div class="right_columns"></div>')
    })
    </script>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="rpost">-115</div>
      <div class="lpost">-91</div>
      <div class="lpost">-99</div>
      <div class="rpost">-181</div>
      <div class="lpost">-19</div>
      <div class="rpost">-135</div>
      <div class="rpost">-85</div>
      <div class="lpost">-39</div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var $container = $('.wrapper').infiniteScroll({
            path: '.next-post',
            append: '.post',
            hideNav: '.pagination',
            status: '.page-load-status',
        });
        $container.on('append.infiniteScroll',
        function(event, response, path, items) {
            $(function() {
                $('.wrapper').each(function() {
                  $(this).find(".lpost").wrapAll('<div class="left_columns"></div>')
                  $(this).find(".rpost").wrapAll('<div class="right_columns"></div>')
                })
            });
        });
        </script>
```

If scroll down three pages result:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left_columns">
    <div class="left_columns">
      <div class="left_columns">
          <div class="lpost">-91</div>
          <div class="lpost">-99</div>
          <div class="lpost">-19</div>
          <div class="lpost">-39</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

have too many left_columns and right_columns divs
how to fix this?

Comment: try `$(this).find(" > .lpost").wrapAll(...)`

Comment: @Damon.s okay i try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to check if the `.right_columns` or `.left_columns` exists or not:

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    var lpost = $(this).find(".lpost"),
        rpost = $(this).find(".rpost"),
        lcol  = $(this).find('.left_columns');

    if(lcol.length){ 
        var rcol = $(this).find('.right_columns');
        lpost.appendTo(lcol);
        rpost.appendTo(rcol);
    }else{
        lpost.wrapAll('<div class="left_columns"></div>');
        rpost.wrapAll('<div class="right_columns"></div>');
    }
})
```